# CODEIGNITER: Create library instance in Controller, access from view

Tags: codeigniter, scope

I have a custom CodeIgniter library class that I create an instance of in a controller. This controller calls a view, and I want to be able to access this instance of the library from the view. I do not want to 're-load' the library, because it would create a new instance.

More specifically, I want to access the class variables in my view ($this->varname).

Is this possible?
Should I be doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you implemented your library class as a normal custom library (e.g. as a library in your application/libraries folder)? If so, then loading it as a library like normal in the constructor of your controller (e.g. `$this->load->library('your_custom_library');`) will make that same instance available in your view, as `$this->your_custom_library`.

Comment: Ahhh I see... I tried to pass it to the view as part of a data array. I tried $this->load->view('myview',$data) with $data['libraryname']. I tried your method and it works great! Appreciate the help for a CodeIgniter newbie!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ben, it's possible and probs a good idea? Here's a helpful pointer: [call my own library within a view in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7994156/call-my-own-library-within-a-view-in-codeigniter)