# call my own library within a view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i just created my own library on this folder (application/library) and following all steps to create individual library,

once i load this library in my controller it execute the function, but when trying to pass it to the view, nothing return

here is my code

**MY OWN FUNCTION**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Common {

            public function date_arabic()
            {
            $daysarabic=array('الأحد','الاثنين','الثلاثاء'
            ,'الأربعاء','الخميس','الجمعة','السبت');
            $monarabic=array('','يناير','فبراير','مارس',
            'أبريل','مايو','يونيو','يوليو'
            ,'أغسطس','سبتمبر','أكتوبر','نوفمبر','ديسمبر');
            $date=getdate(time());
            echo $daysarabic[$date['wday']].' '.$date['mday'].' '.$monarabic[$date['mon']].' '.$date['year']/*.' الوقت الأن '.$date['hours'].':'.$date['minutes'].':'.$date['seconds']*/;
            }       

    }
```

**MY Controller**

```
    //arabic date
    $this->load->library('Common');
    $this->common->date_arabic();
```

here it prints out the data in my own function, i tried to store this in a $data to pass it to the view like that

```
    //arabic date
    $this->load->library('Common');
    $data['date_arabic'] = $this->common->date_arabic();
    ...

    $this->load->view('home_page.php', $data);
```

then when going to view i just type

```
<?php echo $date_arabic ; ?>
```

but nothing returned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function, change the last line from this:

```
echo $daysarabic[$date['wday']].' '.$date['mday'].' '.$monarabic[$date['mon']].' '.$date['year']/*.' الوقت الأن '.$date['hours'].':'.$date['minutes'].':'.$date['seconds']*/;
```

to this:

```
return $daysarabic[$date['wday']].' '.$date['mday'].' '.$monarabic[$date['mon']].' '.$date['year']/*.' الوقت الأن '.$date['hours'].':'.$date['minutes'].':'.$date['seconds']*/;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
when you are writing libraries, you have to manually grab the Codeigniter instance like this

$CI =& get_instance();

then you would use $CI where you would normally use $this to interact with loaded codeigniter resources

so...

instead of

$this->input->post();
you would write

$CI->input->post();


EXAMPLE LIBRARY STRUCTURE

class Examplelib {

    // declare your CI instance class-wide private
    private $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        // get the CI instance and store it class wide
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
    }

    public function lib_function()
    {
        // use it here
        $this->CI->db->etc()
    }

    public function another_func()
    {
        // and here
        $this->CI->input->post();
    }

}
```

Comment: it was diffcult to understand ... please if you can make an example in my own code